# 'Exceeded maximum allocated IDs' in production GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to copy models over from one entity to another, preserving their auto-generated ID. I'm using the following code:

```
key = db.Key.from_path('TargetEntity', source.key().id())
db.allocate_id_range(app, start = source.key().id(), end = source.key().id())
TargetEntity(key = key).put()
```

This works fine in `dev_appserver`, but when running this in production, `allocate_id_range` throws "Exceeded maximum allocated IDs". The ID it is trying to allocate is `5093058741796864L`.

Other issues on StackOverflow mentioning this either started using their own ID generator (which is not a solution), or seem to be due to an issue with unusually high IDs from years ago with a new ID generator (which doesn't seem to apply anymore).

Comment: I had some issues with manually generated IDs when I was using `db` but they went away when I switched to `ndb`.  It is a good idea to switch to `ndb` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So back around June 2013 the default for id allocation in datastore became "scattered ids"

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/05/update-on-datastore-auto-ids.html

The ID you are trying to allocate is a SCATTERED id.  The ID's that allocated_id_range handles are sequential.

What you want is the _reserve_keys function which works with SCATTERED ids and performs the exact operation you want (given a key, tell ID allocation that you have it and that it shouldn't reallocate it).

Unfortunately it will be annoying to get at.  It is located in:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc

and works on protobuf representations of keys.

An alternative solution that works just as well is:

Generate random, non sequential ids using a random number generator with enough bits that collisions are statistically impossible.  Use those in your model keys.

If you want a smaller ID space, or don't trust random number generators then you can use a transaction to verify that the ID hasn't been used.